# How can I make a not allowed cursor on a button?

Tags: html, css, button, cursor

`cursor: not-allowed` function is not working anymore. I have tried the following:

```
button[disabled] {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

This way it's working, but in this case my text button disappears.

Comment: `cursor: not-allowed` is working fine with or without `pointer-events`. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/4d9zxk4j/ - so the problem is somewhere else in your code, please share more.

Comment: What is the use of showing not-allowed cursor on a enabled button? button is clickable anyway.

Comment: I had some other problems. Someone overwrite some bootsrap classes.              {//.btn-default, .btn-info{
// &:hover,
// &:focus,
// &:active,
// &.active {
//  background-color: @color-blue-menu;
//  color: @color-white;
//  border-color: @color-white;
// }
//}{

Answer (score 1):

Here was the problem : someone overwrite the bootsrap classes. Not-allowed is working fine.

```
//.btn-default, .btn-info{
//  &:hover,
//  &:focus,
//  &:active,
//  &.active {
//      background-color: @color-blue-menu;
//      color: @color-white;
//      border-color: @color-white;
//  }
//}
```